# Custom popoverview not showing in modalViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, modalviewcontroller

My hiearchy is that:

```
-----MainViewController with button, which open ViewController2 as modal;
 -----ViewController2 has button, which should open custom popoverview with ViewController3
```

The problem is that, costompopoverView doesn't shows.

There is my code for popoverView showing:

```
    -(IBAction)showPopoverAdressBar:(id)sender forEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    NSLog(@"Click");
    AdressBar *popoverControllesr = [[AdressBar alloc]init];
    popoverControllesr.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, 600, 45);
    popoverControllesr.delegate = self;
    popoverControllesr.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    mypopoverCotroller popoverController = [[mypopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popoverControllesr];

    popoverController.cornerRadius = 20;
    if(_titles!=NULL){

        popoverController.titleText = _titles;}else{
            popoverController.titleText = @"Loading...";
        }
    popoverControllesr.address.text = absoluteString;



    popoverController.popoverBaseColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    popoverController.popoverGradient= YES;

   popoverController.arrowPosition = myPopoverArrowPositionHorizontal;
    [popoverController showPopoverWithTouch:event];


}
```

I don't need the UIPopoverViewController, because it's can't be customized.

Comment: create log of `popoverControllesr`, may be its frame is changing after load.

Comment: I done it, like this `NSLog(@"%@", popoverControllesr.view.frame);` and it says (null).

Comment: no, print `NSLog(@"%i", popoverControllesr.view.frame.origin.x);` and `NSLog(@"%i", popoverControllesr.view.frame.origin.y);`

Comment: it's says 0.00000 for both.

Comment: hmm, print width, height also then recheck your entire code.

Comment: That's good: 45.000000 and 600.000000